# How to create OAuth Bearer tokens in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net

With Owin it was possible to create tokens using  `OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect`but how should I do it with vNext. I'm currently using `"Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuthBearer": "1.0.0-beta3"`

I've tried a few things such as injecting DataProtectors etc. but I haven't had any success yet.